# MvvmCross: Perform command after UICollectionView click

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross with UICollectionViews and it's working pretty fine up to this point.
Since Data Binding is pretty easy with MvvmCross I wanted to find a way to bind the click on UICollectionView's cell to a command (click on cell => navigate to next view). But I haven't found an easy way to do it.

Currently this is my binding from the data source to the collection view:

```
var source = new MvxCollectionViewSource(TextileCollectionView, new NSString("TextileCollectionViewCell"));
TextileCollectionView.Source = source;

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, FirstViewModel>();
set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.SearchResults);
//set.Bind(TextileCollectionView.Tap()).For(tap => tap.Command).To(vm => vm.ShowDetailViewCommand);
set.Apply();
```

The commented line with the binding of the tap works, but of course I don't get the clicked cell and the corresponding data.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use on Xamarin.iOS with MvxCollectionViewController

```
    public sealed override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        if (!_isInitialised)
            return;

        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        CollectionView.RegisterNibForCell (MovieCollectionViewCell.Nib, MovieCollectionViewCell.Key);
        var source = new MoviesCollectionViewDataSource (ViewModel, CollectionView, MovieCollectionViewCell.Key);
        CollectionView.Source = source;

        this.CreateBinding(source).To<HomeViewModel>(vm => vm.MoviesSections).Apply();
        this.CreateBinding(source).For(s => s.SelectionChangedCommand).To<HomeViewModel>(vm => vm.ShowDetailViewCommand).Apply();

        CollectionView.ReloadData();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
set.Bind(source).For("SelectedItemChanged").To(vm => vm.ShowDetailViewCommand);
set.Apply();
```